# Does Helm (or Kubernetes) caches charts?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

I have a chart for Helm that works fine.

I updated couple lines of "template" files to have it set up differently and ran `helm install -n <relaese name> <char dir>`.

But I found that change never gets applied.

when I tried `helm install --dry-run --debug`, I don't see my updates.
(It might be getting the chart from remote ...)

Does Helm cache stuff? I wasn't able to find anything about it...

I am trying to setup hdfs on my cluster using this [link](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/kubernetes-HDFS)

Comment: I try and my configs are usually updated, I tried once again make changes and they were working fine, If you share the exact change, then I can see more in it.

Comment: Do you want to update existing instance or create new instance?

Comment: I can update existing one but fine with restarting. I have been deleting the previous release with --purge option so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had to rebuild dependency after I make a changes

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make changes to a chart that do not make difference to the application when it runs or even that are not included in the Kubernetes resources that are generated (e.g. a change within an if block whose condition evaluates to false). You can use '--dry-run --debug' to see what the template evaluates to and check whether your change is present in the Kubernetes resources that would result from the chart installation. This gives you a quick way to check a chart change without it being installed.

If you were publishing the chart then you could see a delay between publishing and getting it from the hosted repo and might need to run `helm repo update` but you seem to be using the chart source code directly so I would not expect any delay.

Comment: Thank you for the option. it was in fact helpful. However, when I ran `helm install --dry-run --debug`. I do not see the local change I made to chart. Do you know if helm gets chart from remote even though I pass in local path to helm install function?

Comment: happy to chat if you're available - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183578/room-for-ryan-dawson-and-brandon-lee